# How to remove certain empty new lines/blank spaces

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm learning web scraping on my test store and I'm not sure how to properly remove empty new lines from the 'sizes' array.

```js
 const $ = cheerio.load(body)

            $('div.listing').each((i, listing) => {

                let sizes = []

                let productUrl = $(listing).find('a').attr('href')
                let productTitle = $(listing).find('a').attr('title').toUpperCase()
                let productSizes = $(listing).find('.size-cont').text()

                if (products.indexOf(productUrl) == -1) {

                    sizes.push(productSizes)
                    console.log(sizes.join('').replace(/[^\S\r\n]+/g,"").trim()) // issue here

                }

            })
```

Current output:

```
9.0




9.5




10.0




10.5
```

I want it to be:

```
9.0
9.5
10.0
10.5
```

Comment: `.text().trim()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant this?

```js
console.log(
`9.0




9.5




10.0




10.5`
.replace(/(\s)+/g,"$1")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```js
const output = sizes.join('').replace(/[^\S\r\n]+/g,"").trim();
const noWhitespaceOutput.replace(" ", "");
console.log(noWhitespaceOutput);
```